# Make searching easier by renaming [little-big-planet] → [littlebigplanet]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-rename-request

All the tags for the LittleBigPlanet franchise have the game title separated into three separate words, Little Big Planet. This makes questions about the game harder to stumble across due to lower SEO rankings.

I propose renaming the following tags.

- [little-big-planet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-big-planet) → [littlebigplanet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/littlebigplanet)
- [little-big-planet-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-big-planet-2) → [littlebigplanet-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/littlebigplanet-2)
- [little-big-planet-vita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-big-planet-vita) → [littlebigplanet-vita](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/littlebigplanet-vita)
- [little-big-planet-karting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-big-planet-karting) → [littlebigplanet-karting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/littlebigplanet-karting)

---

**Edit**: To demonstrate why this is an issue, [here are the search results when I search the tag **little-big-planet**:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=little-big-planet)

[image: little-big-planet]

Vs [search results for the proper game title, **LittleBigPlanet**:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=LittleBigPlanet)

[image: LittleBigPlanet]

Comment: Other games like the Mass Effect series have their tag words separated by a - . I don't think there's any reason to change it, and in fact makes the tag harder to read.

Comment: Do all of the questions from your second search have a correct tag for the game?

Comment: As much as renaming it may be "proper" based off of how the company writes the title, readability is also important to us, and where the game may have big readable letters on the game cover, the text for it here is small and crammed in a little white box. The hyphens allow people to parse things easier and quicker.

Comment: I really like this format and it would help in some cases.  This could also be confusing later on if a games name becomes changed giving 2 search terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see a need for this. As Kaizerwolf stated, other games have words from their titles broken up. Pretty much all of our tags have titles broken up whether they have spaces in them or not. If I search "littl" in the tags, the tags from the LittleBigPlanet series show up at the top. From there it should be easy to find the correct tag to use. If you want to make it even easier, make sure the tags have good wikis and excerpts. I don't think a tag rename is needed.

Comment: Would a tag synonym be more appropriate?